# Why "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" occurs for string in ajax using ASP.Net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Actually my ajax code is working perfectly if I remove that one particular `string` variable

I am calling ajax, then server will pick some data from SQL Server and store it into string variable. Every variable returning perfectly except that one variable. When I check console, it return exception "**System.IndexOutOfRangeException**"

**Here is my ajax code**

```
$('.list-of-link').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();// add this line
    alert($(this).html());
    //window.location.replace("ReportTotalSalesPivot.aspx");
    var userFileName = $(this).html();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'SavedReports.aspx/getReportDetails',
        method: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: '{userFileName:"' + userFileName + '"}',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success : ReportData = ' + data.d.ReportData);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('Please Call Administrator');
        }
    })
})
```

**WebMethod** code

```
[WebMethod]
    public static SavedReport getReportDetails(string userFileName)
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HQWebMatajer13"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "select ReportData,ReportFilter,FromDate,ToDate,SelectedData,SelectedCoulmn,SelectedRow,HiddenTableRecord ToDate FROM [HQWebMatajer].[dbo].[ReportSave] where UserID=@UserID and UserFileName=@UserFileName";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserFileName", userFileName);

            con.Open();

            SavedReport savedReport = new SavedReport();

            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rd.Read())
            {
                byte[] binaryString = (byte[])rd["ReportData"];
                savedReport.ReportData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(binaryString);

                savedReport.ReportFilter = rd["ReportFilter"].ToString();
                savedReport.FromDate = rd["FromDate"].ToString();
                savedReport.ToDate = rd["ToDate"].ToString();
                savedReport.SelectedData = rd["SelectedData"].ToString();
                savedReport.SelectedColumn = rd["SelectedCoulmn"].ToString();
                savedReport.SelectedRow = rd["SelectedRow"].ToString();
                savedReport.HiddenTableRecord = rd["HiddenTableRecord"].ToString();
            }
            return savedReport;
        }

    }
```

**Error occur in the last variable** `HiddenTableRecord`

> The following record is actual record for `HiddenTableRecord` from SQL Server `tq.StoreID$$$ IN('1001')$$$`

**SavedReport** class code

```
public class SavedReport
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string ReportName { get; set; }
    public string UserFileName { get; set; }
    public string ReportData { get; set; }
    public string ReportFilter { get; set; }
    public string FromDate { get; set; }
    public string ToDate { get; set; }
    public string SelectedData { get; set; }
    public string SelectedColumn { get; set; }
    public string SelectedRow { get; set; }
    public string HiddenTableRecord { get; set; }
}
```

**Error msg**

> {Message: "HiddenTableRecord",…}
>
> ExceptionType:"System.IndexOutOfRangeException"
>
> Message:"HiddenTableRecord"

**Note**

> If I comment this line `savedReport.HiddenTableRecord = rd["HiddenTableRecord"].ToString();`. Error is not occurring and it returns all the records what I expect

Comment: Without reading anything people are giving negative marks. people should give the valid reason now

Comment: i think here is the problem in your query : `,HiddenTableRecord ToDate`, you missed comma i guess

Comment: @ehsansajjad shit.. please wait let me check.

Comment: @ehsansajjad correct. shit. how i did that. i was looking something for an half and hr

Comment: happens sometimes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes because your `SqlDataReader` doesn't contains "HiddenTableRecord"

Maybe there is an issue in your SqlRequest (a comma is missing in your example between *HiddenTableRecord* and *ToDate*):

*"select ReportData,ReportFilter,FromDate,ToDate,SelectedData,SelectedCoulmn,SelectedRow,HiddenTableRecord **,** ToDate FROM [HQWebMatajer].[dbo].[ReportSave] where UserID=@UserID and UserFileName=@UserFileName";*